# How to get upload file name using flask?

Tags: python, flask

Can i get it in str?

```
@app.route("/upload", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_video():
     print(request.files)
######## ImmutableMultiDict([('', <FileStorage: 'test (5).mp4' ('video/mp4')>), ('', <FileStorage: 'test (7).mp4' ('video/mp4')>)]) ############
```

I want to get 'test (5).mp4' and 'test (7).mp4'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filename as follows

```py
file = request.files['file']
file_name = file.filename
```

See the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/#a-gentle-introduction) for an exhaustive example.

Comment: Its only show first file name, i need all of them.